# CS0103 The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context mvc 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I get this error in VS 2022
the ASP.NET application is running, but this error is appearing.
I check the configs according other answers I found in this topic, but everything looks OK.

my cshtml file:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = null;
}
```

in web.config (all about the MVC config):

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0"/>
    <-- more settings here -->
  </appSettings>

    ... 

<namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
 ....
 </namespaces>

<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="..." culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.8.0" newVersion="5.2.8.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

the error:

```
Error   CS0103  The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context
```

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Post your code and the actual full error (including the call stack, error location, any inner exceptions). `ViewBag` exists only in Views. It's used to transfer unstructured data from a controller action to the view.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos there is no more stack trace but this error I wrote.

Comment: That's a compilation error which means the web app can't run. You haven't explained where this snippet comes from, or posted any relevant code. `ViewBag` only exists in views in MVC applications. If you try to use `ViewBag` in any other kind of page you'll get this error. Where *are* you using this? The configuration has nothing to do with the problem although it shows you're using an old ASP.NET Framework instead of Core. MVC 5.2 is 10 years old and shouldn't be used in new projects